# How to re-reference two set method of useState into one in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
                    (parent)
  re-reference the set method here with the new one
 _______________________|__________________________
|                                                  | (original set method) - uplift it
|                               
| (pass it down to child where it is needed)
```

I wanted to pass the reference of the set method of the useState() to a new variable of useState() hook.

something like:

```
// Parent side code..

const [, setNameProp] = useState('');
const [, setDescriptionProp] = useState('');

// here suppose say we are uplifting the state here from the child component
const onSubmit = ({ setName, setDescription }: state) => {
    setNameProp = setName;
    setDescriptionProp = setDescription;
  };

// now I just want to use the setNameProp and setDescriptionProp ahead and pass it further down where needed.
//eg:
<App name={setNameProp}, desc={setDescriptionProp}>
```

How can I make this happen? Can we reassign the method or re-reference them?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make this happen? Can we reassign the method or re-reference them?

You *can* (with some potential hacks), but Don't!

Lift the state the react way i.e. move the ownership (creation of the state) into the parent.

## More

Alternatively you can consider a state manager to move it out of React so you can create it independent of the Virtual Dom tree ([I'm personally biased towards valtio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGY9HvUe2AA)).